# Find the numbers of cow in each group

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm practicing C++ solving some exercises, but after the whole day, I couldn't solve on of them. Here's the exercise:
There are 100 hay and 100 cows divided into 3 groups.
    -Group A: 1 cow needs 5 hay to be full
    -Group B: 1 cow needs 3 hay to be full
    -Group C: 3 cow needs 1 hay to be full
Calculate the number of cows in each group.
If all of them eat at the same time at the same speed then the code is not very hard.

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a, b, c;
    for (a = 1; a <= 20; a++)
    {
        for (b = 1; b <= 32; b++)
        {
            c = 3 * (100 - 5 * c - 3 * c);
            if ((a + b + c == 100)) 
                cout << "Group A " << a << ", group B " << b << ", group c " << c << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

However since they eat at different speeds and some groups may start eating slower than others, some of them won't get full before the hay runs out. Input can be the time begin to eat of each group **(BeginA, BeginB, BeginC)** *(Eg: 0mins, 10mins, 5mins)* and the speed of each group **(SpeedA, SpeedB, SpeedC)** *(measure in minutes per hay)*. And there are at least 2 groups are full. How can you find the numbers of cows in each group?

Edit: I have set up a test case:
BeginA=0, BeginB=10, BeginC=15
SpeedA=5, SpeedB=5, SpeedC=10
After 5 mins, x hay have been eaten. 
10 mins, 2x hay have been eaten (100-2x hay).
15 mins, 2x + y hay have been eaten. 
20 mins, 3x + 2y hay have been eaten.
Repeat until 2 groups are full 
5x+3y+2/3z hay have been eaten
Then I stucked here: If x+y+z=100 and the hay have been eaten=100 then we have the answer.

Edit 2: Welp, still going nowhere, stuck in an infinite loop:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int numCow(int a,int b,int c) {
    int x=0, y=0, z=0;
    for (x = 1; x < 100; x++)
    {
        for (y = 1; y < 100; y++)
        {
            for (z = 1; z < 100; z++)
                if ((x + y + z == 100) && (a * x + b * y + c * z == 300))
                    cout << "Group A " << x << ", Group B " << y << ", Group C " << z << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
int main()

{
    int x, y, z, a=0, b=0, c=0, counter;
    int Sx = 0, Sy = 0, Sz = 0, Bx, By, Bz; 
    x = 0; y = 0; z = 0;
    counter = 0;
    cout << "Begin time (s): ";
    cin >> Bx >> By >> Bz;
    cout << "Speed: ";
    cin >> Sx >> Sy >> Sz;
    Bx += Sx;
    By += Sy;
    Bz += Sz;
    while (true) {
        if (a!=15)
            if (Bx == counter)
            {
                a++;
                Bx += Sx;
            }
        if (b != 9)
            if (By == counter)
            {
                b++;
                By += Sy;
            }
        if (c!=3)
            if (Bz == counter)
            {
                c++;
                Bz += Sz;
            }
        if (a == 15 && b == 9) {
            numCow(a, b, c);
            break;
        }
        if (a == 15 && c == 3) {
            numCow(a, b, c);
            break;
        }
        if (c == 3 && b == 9) {
            numCow(a, b, c);
            break;
        }
        if (a == 15 && b == 9 && c == 3)
        {
            numCow(a, b, c);
            break;
        }
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is the issue that you are running into? And what is it that you have tried?

Comment: I presume the question is how many cows such that they all eat all day?  Perhaps start with all cows in grp C. Move some cows to grp A. You have to move 3 at a time to eat all the hay.. How many until you run out of hay? In the end there are less than 10,000 possible answers.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't display any solutions. Did you expect it to? Actually, it's undefined behavior since it uses `c` uninitialized.

Comment: Recommendation: Solve the problem on paper first and keep notes on the process used. Make sure they are good notes as they will be the basis for both your code and the the step-by-step expectations you need to have when debugging the code.

Comment: I have added my code but still need some help